# Jensen-Shannon Divergence

Tags: python, distance, metrics

I have another question that I was hoping someone could help me with.

I'm using the Jensen-Shannon-Divergence to measure the similarity between two probability distributions.  The similarity scores appear to be correct in the sense that they fall between 1 and 0 given that one uses the base 2 logarithm, with 0 meaning that the distributions are equal.

However, I'm not sure whether there is in fact an error somewhere and was wondering whether someone might be able to say 'yes it's correct' or 'no, you did something wrong'.

Here is the code:

```
from numpy import zeros, array
from math import sqrt, log


class JSD(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.log2 = log(2)


    def KL_divergence(self, p, q):
        """ Compute KL divergence of two vectors, K(p || q)."""
        return sum(p[x] * log((p[x]) / (q[x])) for x in range(len(p)) if p[x] != 0.0 or p[x] != 0)

    def Jensen_Shannon_divergence(self, p, q):
        """ Returns the Jensen-Shannon divergence. """
        self.JSD = 0.0
        weight = 0.5
        average = zeros(len(p)) #Average
        for x in range(len(p)):
            average[x] = weight * p[x] + (1 - weight) * q[x]
            self.JSD = (weight * self.KL_divergence(array(p), average)) + ((1 - weight) * self.KL_divergence(array(q), average))
        return 1-(self.JSD/sqrt(2 * self.log2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    J = JSD()
    p = [1.0/10, 9.0/10, 0]
    q = [0, 1.0/10, 9.0/10]
    print J.Jensen_Shannon_divergence(p, q)
```

The problem is that I feel that the scores are not high enough when comparing two text documents, for instance. However, this is purely a subjective feeling.

Any help is, as always, appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try comparing output to [this Matlab script?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20689-jensen-shannon-divergence) Or run it in Octave.

Comment: The `if p[x] != 0.0 or p[x] != 0` looks strange.

Comment: if p[x] != 0.0 or p[x] != 0 is used to make sure that we don't consider entries which are zero, whether they are floats or integers, is that what you were referring to? Or did you mean that this line is weird full stop?  Many thanks.

Comment: `p[x] != 0` is the same because `0.0 == 0`. That's why I suspected there might be a typo there.

Answer (score 27):

Note that the scipy entropy call below is the Kullback-Leibler divergence.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scipy.stats import entropy
from numpy.linalg import norm
import numpy as np

def JSD(P, Q):
    _P = P / norm(P, ord=1)
    _Q = Q / norm(Q, ord=1)
    _M = 0.5 * (_P + _Q)
    return 0.5 * (entropy(_P, _M) + entropy(_Q, _M))
```

Also note that the test case in the Question looks erred??  The sum of the p distribution does not add to 1.0.

See: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda361.htm

Comment: Importing and using `norm` is not needed, as `entropy` will normalize the distributions if they do not add up to 1 (see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html). However, to compute `_M` like that, `_P` and `_Q` need to be `numpy.ndarray` objects.

Comment: @Tur1ng note that norm is needed because the calculation of `_M` requires that `_P` and `_Q` are probability distributions (already normalized).  Also note that lists are coerced as numpy arrays so this is fine: `[2, 4] / np.array([1, 2])`

Comment: @DougShore actually, since `scipy.stats.entropy` normalizes the distributions, you don't need to normalize `_P` and `_Q` to compute `_M`, you only need them to sum up to the same value, and you can probably save a few computations. However, this is much more readable like this. On the other hand, I would prefer functions that don't do unnecessary computations, and assume that the input are normalized probabilities.

Comment: So, in the @Doug Shore's code do I need to have the `P, Q` frequency lists (`list_a` and `list_b`) in my occasion: `list_a = [1, 100, 40, 1200, 0, 4]` and `list_b = [23, 5600, 11, 0, 40, 340]` as un-normalized as you see it above? Or should I normalize them before feed them in the  `JSD(P, Q)` function?

Comment: @just_learning the JSD function normalizes the inputs (as probability distributions), so yes JSD(list_a, list_b) will work

Answer (score 19):

Since the *Jensen-Shannon* **distance** ([`distance.jensenshannon`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon.html?highlight=jensenshannon#scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon)) has been included in `Scipy 1.2`, the *Jensen-Shannon* **divergence** can be obtained as the square of the Jensen-Shannon distance:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

distance.jensenshannon([1.0/10, 9.0/10, 0], [0, 1.0/10, 9.0/10]) ** 2
# 0.5306056938642212
```

Answer (score 9):

Get some data for distributions with known divergence and compare your results against those known values.

BTW: the sum in KL_divergence may be rewritten using the [zip built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) like this:

```
sum(_p * log(_p / _q) for _p, _q in zip(p, q) if _p != 0)
```

This does away with lots of "noise" and is also much more "pythonic". The double comparison with `0.0` and `0` is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

A general version, for n probability distributions, in python

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import entropy as H


def JSD(prob_distributions, weights, logbase=2):
    # left term: entropy of misture
    wprobs = weights * prob_distributions
    mixture = wprobs.sum(axis=0)
    entropy_of_mixture = H(mixture, base=logbase)

    # right term: sum of entropies
    entropies = np.array([H(P_i, base=logbase) for P_i in prob_distributions])
    wentropies = weights * entropies
    sum_of_entropies = wentropies.sum()

    divergence = entropy_of_mixture - sum_of_entropies
    return(divergence)

# From the original example with three distributions:
P_1 = np.array([1/2, 1/2, 0])
P_2 = np.array([0, 1/10, 9/10])
P_3 = np.array([1/3, 1/3, 1/3])

prob_distributions = np.array([P_1, P_2, P_3])
n = len(prob_distributions)
weights = np.empty(n)
weights.fill(1/n)

print(JSD(prob_distributions, weights))
#0.546621319446
```

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly following the math in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence):

```
def jsdiv(P, Q):
    """Compute the Jensen-Shannon divergence between two probability distributions.

    Input
    -----
    P, Q : array-like
        Probability distributions of equal length that sum to 1
    """

    def _kldiv(A, B):
        return np.sum([v for v in A * np.log2(A/B) if not np.isnan(v)])

    P = np.array(P)
    Q = np.array(Q)

    M = 0.5 * (P + Q)

    return 0.5 * (_kldiv(P, M) +_kldiv(Q, M))
```